# Webpush::Unauthorized: host: fcm.googleapis.com, #<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-push, vapid

I am trying to integrate Web Push Notification on the Web Application I am maintaining. I am using this github repo https://github.com/zaru/webpush as my guide.

After following what is included in that guide, and run this command at my terminal:

```
Webpush.payload_send(message: "Test", endpoint: n.endpoint, p256dh: n.p256dh_key, auth: n.auth_key, vapid: {private_key: "gAdLtJoNQHDXsd1iYxrvttW3YybuJX4GkN8LDMbSIuw=", public_key: "BHByXuCTQs7UuoqBN2MeLjL_gUHfsuhxKkV_QOdhm9mw9Ohl3giAoxdwtwuoXqYnIbaa7UaTC1BvwS8yv_pNOAU="} )
```

Suddenly, I encountered this error, does someone here encountered the same error as I did? How did you resolved it? Thank you in advance.

```
Webpush::Unauthorized: host: fcm.googleapis.com, #<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>
body:
the key in the authorization header does not correspond to the sender ID used to subscribe this user. Please ensure you are using the correct sender ID and server Key from the Firebase console.
```